# Resharper expression is always false

Tags: c#, resharper

Given the following chunk of code..

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null) return null;
if (HttpContext.Current.User == null) return null;
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null) return null;
return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Resharper is telling me that the third line is always false. Considering that Identity is a reference type how can Resharper make that guarantee?

Comment: I suspect it has some annotations which "guarantee" it. Note that in C# 6 this can be refactored to: `return HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper comes with so called ["External Annotations"](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html).

Using these annotations R# assumes that specific properties / arguments / ... can never be `null`. (You should see a `[NotNull]` attribute annotation after pressing Crtl+Shift+F1 on the `Identity` property.)

BUT: This specific annotation seems to be a bug (see [RSRP-398551](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-398551)) and is already fixed in the current version of the external annotations.